# Authenticate with firebase owner before pulling data down

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

So I have this code written out:

```
var temp_photo = storageRef.child('user_photos/'+snap.key+'/')
var y = r.insertCell(17).innerHTML = snap.val().photo_url;
temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
  console.log(downloadURL);
  //var y = r.insertCell(17).innerHTML = '<img src="'+downloadURL+'" width="50" height="50" />';
})
```

works fine, it shows the image url in firebase:

```
user_photos/07KMSXj5QBYHj55555558bSLIkK2/D41FB90B-1111-5555-2222-22F86D69883F.jpg
```

this is the correct path to the image, the problem is, im not trying to display the url, i want to display the actual image, any help with this?

my configs are set up correct like this:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "55555",
  authDomain: "MY-APP.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://MY-APP.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "MYAPP",
  storageBucket: "APP.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "44444",
  appId: "1:5555555:web:5555555"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And my firebase security set up like this:

I think it has something to do with permission, these are mine set now:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read
      allow write//: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I console.log the downloadURL and get the following printed

It looks like its throwing a 404 error

**[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (user_photos/07KMSXj5QBYHj55555558bSLIkK2, line 0)**

looks like its failing to get `user_photos/07KMSXj5QBYHj55555558bSLIkK2`

but it should be getting a full url (the image in the folder):

```
user_photos/07KMSXj5QBYHj55555558bSLIkK2/D41FB90B-1111-5555-2222-22F86D69883F.jpg
```

Here is also an image of what gets logged:

[image]

**I think I need to authenticate the user before It can get the downloadURL**

I have something like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var email="my@gmail.com";
var password="mypassword";
//Sign In User with Email and Password
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

with the following set up:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

getting an error that auth() is not a function?

Comment: What you keep showing as a URL isn't actually a URL.  An actual download URL will begin with "https://"